# Why is my object having having trouble getting created?

Tags: java, arrays, object

I made a program to create a object array that stores two CheckingAccount objects and one SavingAccount object. I ran into a simple problem it seems that for my main method I want to main a CheckingAccount object but the problem is there seems to be a error with the constructor. I have set it up the same way before with a different exercise so I am confused on how the construtor is wrong. here is the code:

```
public class program4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BankAccount[] array = new BankAccount[3];
        boolean y = true;
        CheckingAccount no1 = new CheckingAccount("John","Smith","abc@aol.com",30.0,false,30.0);
    }
    public static class  BankAccount{

        private static int accountId;
        private static final int TOTAL_ACCOUNT_NUMBER = accountId;
        private static String firstName;
        private String lastName;
        private String custEmail;
        public static double balance;
        private  Date dateCreated;
        BankAccount(String firstName, String lastName, String email, double balance){
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
            this.custEmail = email;
            this.balance = balance;
            this.dateCreated = new Date();

            }
        public void deposit(double amount) {
            balance = balance + amount;
        }
        Date getDate() {
            return this.dateCreated;
        }
        int getID() {
            return accountId;
        }
        String getName() {
            return firstName +" "+ lastName;
        }
        String getEmail(){
            return custEmail;
            }
        double getBalance() {
            return balance;
        }

        public void withdraw(double amount) {
            balance =balance - amount;
        }
        public String toString() {
            return "Account ID: " + accountId + " /nName: " + firstName+" "+lastName+"/nEmail: "+custEmail+"/nBalance: "+balance+ "\nDate Created: "+ dateCreated;

        }
    }
    public class CheckingAccount extends BankAccount{
        private boolean hasDirectDeposit;
        private double minBal;
        CheckingAccount(String firstName,String lastName,String email,double deposit, boolean hasDirectDeposit,double minBal){

            super(firstName,lastName,email,balance);

            this.hasDirectDeposit = hasDirectDeposit;
            this.minBal = minBal;

        }

        public boolean getDirectDeposit() {
            return hasDirectDeposit;
        }
        public void setDirectDeposit(boolean flag){
            hasDirectDeposit = flag;
        }
        public double getMinBal() {
            return minBal;
        }
        public void setMinBal(double bal) {
            minBal = bal;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return "Account ID: " + getID()+"/nName: "+ getName() + "/nEmail: "+ getEmail()+"/nBalance: "+ getBalance()+ "/nDate Created: "+ getDate() +
            "/nDirect Deposit: " + getDirectDeposit() + "/nMinimum Balance: "+ getMinBal();

        }
    }
    public class SavingsAccount extends BankAccount{
        private double interestRate;
        SavingsAccount(String firstName,String lastName,String email,double balance,double intRate){
            super(firstName,lastName,email,balance);
            this.interestRate = intRate;
        }
        public double getInterestRate() {
            return interestRate;
        }
        public void setInterestRate(double intRate) {
            interestRate =intRate;
        }
        public String toString() {
            return "Account ID: " + getID()+"/nName: "+ getName() + "/nEmail: "+ getEmail()+"/nBalance: "+ getBalance()+ "/nDate Created: "+ getDate() +
                    "/nInterest Rate: "+ getInterestRate();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `CheckingAccount` and `SavingsAccount` aren't `static`.  You can't construct an instance of one of them without an instance of `program4` to 'hold' them.  Should be fine if you just add `static` to both their declarations (I haven't actually checked the rest of the code though).

Comment: If you have a static class there will only ever be one of them.  Not very useful when you want something like a `BankAccount` to hold user names and accounts - unless you are only ever going to have one BankAccount

Comment: @user2478398 Your comment is wrong, see the second comment for details...

Comment: @csabinho That's really not correct.  A `static` class declaration means that it does not need to be constructed from an instance of `program4`.  There can still be multiple instances of that `static class`...  https://ideone.com/rHeWxZ

Answer (score 1):

Inner classes are 'instance' by default (the opposite of `static`). Top-level classes are inherently 'static' (although trying to mark them as such isn't legal, they just are, they can't not be). These 'instance inner classes' can be useful, but mostly, they are confusing. I suggest you forget they exist for now*, and always, *always* mark your inner classes with `static`, at which point your problems will go away.

*) If you must know, non-static-inners act as if they have a hidden final field of the outer class type, and all constructors act as if they have a hidden parameter to set it. Any call to any constructor in a place where a `this` reference exists of the right type silently inserts that reference, but if not, you have to use the extremely exotic `outerRef.new NonStaticInner()` syntax that many java programmers won't even recognize. In other words: Don't use these unless you really, really, know what you are doing and are very sure they are the best fit to the situation.

Comment: I see what you meant but another error pops up which is No enclosing instance of type Program4 is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type 
  Program4 (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance ofProgram4).

Comment: @Gitown This is exactly what this answer, and my comment above tell you how to address.  You either need `program4 x = new program4();  x.new SavingsAccount()` (unlikely what you want to do).  Or to declare the `SavingsAccount` and `CheckingAccount` classes as `static`.